# Estimate for the diameter of a facet of best-approximating polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let $P$ be a convex polytope in $\Bbb R^n$ with $N$ vertices that is best-approximating for the Euclidean unit ball $B$ under the symmetric difference metric. I am trying to prove the following statement: there is a facet $F$ of $P$ and an absolute constant $C$ such that $\text{diam}(F) \leq CN^{-1/(n-1)}$.

It is known that for each facet $F$ a best-approximating polytope, $|F\cap B|=|F\cap B^c|$, where $|\cdot|$ denotes $(n-1)$-volume. It is also known that $|B\Delta P| \sim \frac{1}{2}\text{ldel}_{n-1}|\partial B|^{\frac{n+1}{n-1}}N^{-2/(n-1)}$ where $\text{ldel}_{n-1}$ is a constant that depends only on the dimension $n$ and satisfies $\frac{c_1}{n} \leq \text{ldel}_{n-1}\leq c_2$ for some absolute constants $c_1,c_2>0$.

Do you think that the diameter inequality is true? If so, any suggestions on a proof strategy would be appreciated. I tried to use a contradiction argument to violate the asymptotic formula, but so far I have failed in my attempts.

Thanks in advance.